# IntelliJ IDEA Render error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up IntelliJ IDEA for programming android but I can't render the main.xml.

> org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of
>   the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ
>   IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderServiceFactory.loadLibrary(RenderServiceFactory.java:158)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderServiceFactory.create(RenderServiceFactory.java:73)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getRenderServiceFactory(AndroidTargetData.java:132)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderUtil.renderLayout(RenderUtil.java:105)
>     at
>   com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$8.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:346)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>     at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:289)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

[image]

This is the exception I get when I try to open the main.xml with the Android GUI Designer (IntelliJ Utility). I have the latest IDE version so I don't know what's happening here.

Comment: Happened to me as well, when I upgraded to the latest SDK Build-tools version. Installing the older version (18.0.1) could probably help.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

IDEA does not have a render version for 4.3 yet. Try select version of Android that is less than 4.3 in the dropdown in the preview. It works for me.

Answer (score 72):

In the preview tab simply open the last drop-down list and pick the lower Android SDK. In my case, I picked Android 4.4.2 and the preview appeared instantly.

[image]

Comment: you should uncheck "automatically pick best" so that you dont have to repeat this step every time.

Comment: @kodintent Or you can uninstall Android L since hardly anyone codes the app against it. But if you do prepare your app for L, then it's a recommended option.

Comment: Works for me too. Despite of having 2 versions of android, I saw the upper version of android selected in dropdown. Unselecting that and selecting the lower version as suggested in answer fixed my issue. Thanks man! you saved my day!!!

Comment: Thanks for showing the image for changing the SDK. Woohoo, it renders and runs!!!

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be an incompatibility between IDEA and the latest release of the Android SDK Build-tools (18.1). Installing the slightly older version 18.0.1 should fix the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to use 18.0.1 without uninstalling 18.1?

Comment: target lower android version

Answer (score 0):

In the preview tab simply open the last drop-down list and pick the lower Android SDK. In my case, I picked Android 4.4.2 and the preview appeared instantly.

it works for me