# This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, sdk

I've read here [Intellij Idea Render error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872426/intellij-idea-render-error) to choose the older version API in dropdown list but the problem is that the oldest version is 4.4 and it still doesnt work. How to solve this problem? What are the steps to install older API?

Comment: Why can't you update IntelliJ?

Comment: What version is IntelliJ?

Comment: @whowantsakookie 13.1 version

Answer (score 0):

You have three options.

1. If you still want to use IntelliJ and use the KitKat API, then you'll have to wait until they update the stable branch, or give the [EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/EAP) a try.
2. You could use another IDE such as [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) which is based off of IntelliJ (I use this and would highly recommend it)
3. Use a lower API level. You won't be targeting the latest and greatest, but if you're not going to be publishing the app, I wouldn't worry about it. To do this, open the Android SDK Manager and install API 18(?) or less.